# How can I define new "d" attribute from a resized/scaled SVG path?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

**My issues**

Currently, I have positioned the pathIcon along the 'd' path of the SVG path. However, if I change the size of my SVG, the 'd' attribute must also change.
How can I define a new 'd' that resembles the old SVG path with the new size? I don't know how to define a new 'd' in JavaScript.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let svg        = document.querySelector(".svg-path");
  let mPath      = document.getElementById("Path_440");
  let strokePath = document.getElementById("theFill");
  let pathIcon   = document.getElementById("pathIcon");

  const svgRect = svg.getBBox();
  const width   = svgRect.width;
  const height  = svgRect.height;
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

  function defineNewOffsetPath()
    {
    /**my issues : defineNewOffsetPath 
      mPath.setAttribute("d", newPath) 
      how to define a path look like old path with new size
    **/
    pathIcon.style.offsetPath = `path('${mPath.getAttribute("d")}')`;
    }

   defineNewOffsetPath();
})
```

```css
.svg-path {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#pathIcon {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 25px;
  offset-rotate: 0rad;
  transition: 0.2s;
  offset-distance: 0%;
}

#Path_440 {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #001d36;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 175px"></div>
<div id="scrollDiv" style="position: relative">
  <svg class="svg-path" viewBox="0 0 0 0" fill="none">
    <defs>
      <path id="Path_440"
        d="M1293 2S1277 76.47 1197 93.5C1105.55 112.97 888.33 91.07 772.5 100.5 545.5 100.5 302.61 125.94 279 295.5 268 374.5 265.11 419.83 268 503S269.9 645.65 305 741C346.77 854.46 770 838.5 1094.5 832 1366 842.5 1676.02 792 1766 1011 1803.18 1101.5 1766 1457.5 1766 1493.5 1766 1561 1696 1613.5 1618 1627.5 1465 1627.5 1188.11 1632.5 1003.5 1632.5 732.5 1632.5 369.53 1605.69 312 1717.5 271.61 1796 276 1920 276 1982 277.12 2074.28 272.55 2144.17 312 2258 339.86 2338.39 721.15 2324.5 981 2324.5 1297 2324.5 1677.34 2307.5 1739.5 2403.5 1793.57 2487 1772.73 2616.18 1772.73 2765 1772.73 2893 1770.73 2997.5 1652 3032 1612.67 3043.43 1237 3032 893 3032 405.5 3032 2 3030 2 3030"
        stroke="#020878" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="20 20" />
    </defs>
    <use href="#Path_440" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="20 10"></use>
    <use id="theFill" href="#Path_440" stroke-dasharray="1991.82, 9259.88" stroke-width="10" stroke="#4cacff"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg id="pathIcon" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect width="100" height="200" fill="url(#pattern0)" />
    <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
        <use xlink:href="#image0_873_8619" transform="scale(0.00353357 0.00176678)" />
      </pattern>
      <image id="image0_873_8619" width="283" height="566" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA" />
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank @Mister Jojo for helping me edit the format

Comment: see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#b%C3%A9zier_curves

Comment: @Mister Jojo: sorry, edited the prettyfied path data string as it actually breaks setting the `offsetPath` property (doesn't accept new lines)

Comment: @dinhthoi nguyen: I highly recommend to simplify the pathIcon markup - mainly the nested image that can't be rendered. Broken images are always a bit irritating. You can use free placeholder services like lorempicsum etc to apply a dummy image source for So snippets.

Comment: @herrstrietzel Thank you, I will pay attention to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you only need to scale your path data proportional – it is pretty straight forward:

- parse your stringified path data (from the `d` attribute)
- scale all point related command values by a scaling factor (you need to exclude `a` arc command values like x-axis-rotation, largeArc, and sweep flag)
- stringify the path data to a `d` attribute

```js
let svg = document.querySelector(".svg-path");
let mPath = document.getElementById("Path_440");
let strokePath = document.getElementById("theFill");
let pathIcon = document.getElementById("pathIcon");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // auto adjust viewBox
  let svgRect = svg.getBBox();
  let width = svgRect.width;
  let height = svgRect.height;
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

  // update offset path
  defineNewOffsetPath();
});


function defineNewOffsetPath() {
  
  // retrieve the current scale from SVG transformation matrix
  let matrix = svg.getCTM();
  let scale = matrix.a;
  
  // parse path data
  let d = mPath.getAttribute("d");
  let pathData = parsePathData(d);

  //scale pathdata
  pathData = scalePathData(pathData, scale);

  // apply scaled pathdata as stringified d attribute value
  d = pathDataToD(pathData);
  pathIcon.style.offsetPath = `path('${d}')`;
}

// recalculate offset path on resize
window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  defineNewOffsetPath();
});

// just for illustration
resizeObserver()
function resizeObserver() {
  defineNewOffsetPath();
}
new ResizeObserver(resizeObserver).observe(scrollDiv)




/**
* sclae path data proportional
*/
function scalePathData(pathData, scale = 1) {
  let pathDataScaled = [];
  pathData.forEach((com, i) => {
    let { type, values } = com;
    let comT = {
      type: type,
      values: []
    };

    switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
      // lineto shorthands
      case "h":
        comT.values = [values[0] * scale]; // horizontal - x-only
        break;
      case "v":
        comT.values = [values[0] * scale]; // vertical - x-only
        break;

      // arcto
      case "a":
        comT.values = [
          values[0] * scale, // rx: scale
          values[1] * scale, // ry: scale
          values[2], // x-axis-rotation: keep it 
          values[3], // largeArc: dito
          values[4], // sweep: dito
          values[5] * scale, // final x: scale
          values[6] * scale // final y: scale
        ];
        break;

      /**
      * Other point based commands: L, C, S, Q, T
      * scale all values
      */
      default:
        if (values.length) {
          comT.values = values.map((val, i) => {
            return val * scale;
          });
        }
    }
    pathDataScaled.push(comT);
  });
  return pathDataScaled;
}

/**
* parse stringified path data used in d attribute
* to an array of computable command data
*/
function parsePathData(d) {
  d = d
    // remove new lines, tabs an comma with whitespace
    .replace(/[\n\r\t|,]/g, " ")
    // pre trim left and right whitespace
    .trim()
    // add space before minus sign
    .replace(/(\d)-/g, "$1 -")
    // decompose multiple adjacent decimal delimiters like 0.5.5.5 => 0.5 0.5 0.5
    .replace(/(\.)(?=(\d+\.\d+)+)(\d+)/g, "$1$3 ");

  let pathData = [];
  let cmdRegEx = /([mlcqazvhst])([^mlcqazvhst]*)/gi;
  let commands = d.match(cmdRegEx);

  // valid command value lengths
  let comLengths = {
    m: 2,
    a: 7,
    c: 6,
    h: 1,
    l: 2,
    q: 4,
    s: 4,
    t: 2,
    v: 1,
    z: 0
  };
  commands.forEach((com) => {
    let type = com.substring(0, 1);
    let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();
    let isRel = type === typeRel;
    let chunkSize = comLengths[typeRel];

    // split values to array
    let values = com.substring(1, com.length).trim().split(" ").filter(Boolean);

    /**
     * A - Arc commands
     * large arc and sweep flags
     * are boolean and can be concatenated like
     * 11 or 01
     * or be concatenated with the final on path points like
     * 1110 10 => 1 1 10 10
     */
    if (typeRel === "a" && values.length != comLengths.a) {
      let n = 0,
        arcValues = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        let value = values[i];

        // reset counter
        if (n >= chunkSize) {
          n = 0;
        }
        // if 3. or 4. parameter longer than 1
        if ((n === 3 || n === 4) && value.length > 1) {
          let largeArc = n === 3 ? value.substring(0, 1) : "";
          let sweep = n === 3 ? value.substring(1, 2) : value.substring(0, 1);
          let finalX = n === 3 ? value.substring(2) : value.substring(1);
          let comN = [largeArc, sweep, finalX].filter(Boolean);
          arcValues.push(comN);
          n += comN.length;
        } else {
          // regular
          arcValues.push(value);
          n++;
        }
      }
      values = arcValues.flat().filter(Boolean);
    }

    // string  to number
    values = values.map(Number);

    // if string contains repeated shorthand commands - split them
    let hasMultiple = values.length > chunkSize;
    let chunk = hasMultiple ? values.slice(0, chunkSize) : values;
    let comChunks = [
      {
        type: type,
        values: chunk
      }
    ];

    // has implicit or repeated commands – split into chunks
    if (hasMultiple) {
      let typeImplicit = typeRel === "m" ? (isRel ? "l" : "L") : type;
      for (let i = chunkSize; i < values.length; i += chunkSize) {
        let chunk = values.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
        comChunks.push({
          type: typeImplicit,
          values: chunk
        });
      }
    }
    comChunks.forEach((com) => {
      pathData.push(com);
    });
  });

  /**
   * first M is always absolute/uppercase -
   * unless it adds relative linetos
   * (facilitates d concatenating)
   */
  pathData[0].type = "M";
  return pathData;
}

/**
 * serialize pathData array to
 * d attribute string
 */
function pathDataToD(pathData, decimals = 3) {
  let d = ``;
  pathData.forEach((com) => {
    d += `${com.type}${com.values
      .map((val) => {
        return +val.toFixed(decimals);
      })
      .join(" ")}`;
  });
  return d;
}
```

```css
html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


.svg-path {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
}

#pathIcon {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  offset-rotate: 0deg;
  offset-distance: 10%;
}


#scrollDiv{
resize:both;
overflow:auto;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollDiv" style="position: relative">
  <svg class="svg-path" viewBox="0 0 0 0" fill="none">
    <defs>
      <path id="Path_440"
        d="M1293 2 s-16 74.47-96 91.5c-91.45 19.47-308.67-2.43-424.5 7-227 0-469.89 25.44-493.5 195-11 79-13.89 124.33-11 207.5s1.9 142.65 37 238c41.77 113.46 465 97.5 789.5 91 271.5 10.5 581.52-40 671.5 179 37.18 90.5 0 446.5 0 482.5 0 67.5-70 120-148 134-153 0-429.89 5-614.5 5-271 0-633.97-26.81-691.5 85-40.39 78.5-36 202.5-36 264.5 1.12 92.28-3.45 162.17 36 276 27.86 80.39 409.15 66.5 669 66.5 316 0 696.34-17 758.5 79 54.07 83.5 33.23 212.68 33.23 361.5 0 128-2 232.5-120.73 267-39.33 11.43-415 0-759 0-487.5 0-891-2-891-2"
         />
    </defs>
    <use class="stroke" href="#Path_440" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="20 10"></use>
    <use class="stroke" id="theFill" href="#Path_440" stroke-dasharray="925.988 9259.88" stroke-width="10" stroke="#4cacff"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg id="pathIcon" fill="none">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @herrstrietzel for helping me, that's exactly what I needed, but may I ask you one question: how can you edit the default 'd' attribute in my question become new line without altering its appearance? Did you use any extension to convert it?

Comment: Could you please take a look at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78214621/how-can-i-scroll-to-move-svg-centered-in-the-window-along-the-path-with-svg-resi) to help me solve new issues with adding scroll events to your modified code? Thank you very much.