# How can I convert attribute "d" of SVG path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I got this answer from a stranger. Could you let me know how they can change the 'd' attribute of this SVG to another 'd' attribute while still maintaining its shape? I wonder if they used some browser extension or some application?

**From**

```xml
 <svg class="svg-path" viewBox="0 0 0 0" fill="none">
    <defs>
      <path id="Path_440"
        d="M1293 2S1277 76.47 1197 93.5C1105.55 112.97 888.33 91.07 772.5 100.5 545.5 100.5 302.61 125.94 279 295.5 268 374.5 265.11 419.83 268 503S269.9 645.65 305 741C346.77 854.46 770 838.5 1094.5 832 1366 842.5 1676.02 792 1766 1011 1803.18 1101.5 1766 1457.5 1766 1493.5 1766 1561 1696 1613.5 1618 1627.5 1465 1627.5 1188.11 1632.5 1003.5 1632.5 732.5 1632.5 369.53 1605.69 312 1717.5 271.61 1796 276 1920 276 1982 277.12 2074.28 272.55 2144.17 312 2258 339.86 2338.39 721.15 2324.5 981 2324.5 1297 2324.5 1677.34 2307.5 1739.5 2403.5 1793.57 2487 1772.73 2616.18 1772.73 2765 1772.73 2893 1770.73 2997.5 1652 3032 1612.67 3043.43 1237 3032 893 3032 405.5 3032 2 3030 2 3030"
        stroke="#020878" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="20 20" />
    </defs>
    <use href="#Path_440" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="20 10"></use>
    <use id="theFill" href="#Path_440" stroke-dasharray="1991.82, 9259.88" stroke-width="10" stroke="#4cacff"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg id="pathIcon" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect width="100" height="200" fill="url(#pattern0)" />
    <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
        <use xlink:href="#image0_873_8619" transform="scale(0.00353357 0.00176678)" />
      </pattern>
      <image id="image0_873_8619" width="283" height="566" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA" />
    </defs>
  </svg>
```

**To**

```xml
 <svg class="svg-path" viewBox="0 0 0 0" fill="none">
    <defs>
      <path id="Path_440"
        d="M1293 2 s-16 74.47-96 91.5c-91.45 19.47-308.67-2.43-424.5 7-227 0-469.89 25.44-493.5 195-11 79-13.89 124.33-11 207.5s1.9 142.65 37 238c41.77 113.46 465 97.5 789.5 91 271.5 10.5 581.52-40 671.5 179 37.18 90.5 0 446.5 0 482.5 0 67.5-70 120-148 134-153 0-429.89 5-614.5 5-271 0-633.97-26.81-691.5 85-40.39 78.5-36 202.5-36 264.5 1.12 92.28-3.45 162.17 36 276 27.86 80.39 409.15 66.5 669 66.5 316 0 696.34-17 758.5 79 54.07 83.5 33.23 212.68 33.23 361.5 0 128-2 232.5-120.73 267-39.33 11.43-415 0-759 0-487.5 0-891-2-891-2"
         />
    </defs>
    <use class="stroke" href="#Path_440" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="20 10"></use>
    <use class="stroke" id="theFill" href="#Path_440" stroke-dasharray="925.988 9259.88" stroke-width="10" stroke="#4cacff"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg id="pathIcon" fill="none">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  </svg>
```

I tried to search but no result

Comment: There are multiple ways to encode the same shape with different `d` values (e.g. using relative moves, etc.). What's your end goal?

Comment: @AKX I follow to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78211045/how-can-i-define-new-d-attribute-from-a-resized-scaled-svg-path?noredirect=1&fbclid=IwAR0zGAT1cF5OOYPjBMUr1_hjBQF62BH4QcjWBEo67TLTaM3_P_o4hybD8Fo#comment137885947_78211045) and I have a little curiosity about how they convert the 'd' attribute in HTML.

Comment: `some browser extension or some application` - no, it just works based on the javascript code in the post you linked.  When the page loads it scales the path by calling defineNewOffsetPath

Comment: @James But I saw him modify attribute 'd' in the HTML before writing about the function. And I wonder why he was able to do that.

Comment: For one single d-path use the online tool: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

Comment: This is [a pen by Lea Verou](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv) allowing you to change the d attribute from what you have (first example) to **All-relative path** i.e where all commands are lower case (second example)

Comment: What I did was some optimisation to minify the path data `d` string by 1. rounding values to 2 decimals. 2. converting all commands to relative 3. apply all commands to shorthands (if applicable). Pretty much any kind of conversion requires to parse the stringified path data to get a computable set of data.  You may have a look at my own path data [parsing repository](https://github.com/herrstrietzel/svg-parse-path-normalized?tab=readme-ov-file#1-basic-functionality-and-helpers) which lists some common conversions. The parser I used in the previous post is just a stripped down version.

Comment: As commented by @Danny '365CSI' Engelman and enxaneta there are many online tools that can apply various conversions. "under the hood" they all rely on the described concept: parse path then recalculate values. There are also JS libraries that include many conversion methods like snap.svg, svg-commander, svgPath etc. So you may call these javascript libraries "extensions" as there are no inbuilt browser methods for parsing and converting path data.